# How to export and import html div content in draft js?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I use **draft-js-export-html** and **draft-js-import-html** to export and import my HTML content to editor.

But when I try to export HTML by `stateToHTML` function, it also remove all my HTML `div` content.

Anyone know solution to keep `div` tag content when export from `contentState` and import HTML with `div` tag content to `contentState`?

```
onChange(newState) {
    this.setState({editorState: newState});

    if (typeof this.props.onChange != "undefined") {
        let contentState = newState.getCurrentContent();
        let plainText = contentState.getPlainText();
        let htmlContent = stateToHTML(contentState, options); 

        console.log("after", htmlContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Including code snippets might get you more attention.

Comment: `onChange(newState) {
        this.setState({editorState: newState});

        if (typeof this.props.onChange != "undefined") {
            let contentState = newState.getCurrentContent();
            let plainText = contentState.getPlainText();
            
            let htmlContent = stateToHTML(contentState, options);

            console.log("after", htmlContent);
        }
    }
` My code is simple, I just want **htmlContent** has enough content with div tag inside.